# Stanford Neural Network Dependency Parser -filelist

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am a newbie in using Stanford DepParser

I want to proceed several sentences with Stanford DepParser.
If there any way instead of **-textFile** to use the list of files like **-filelist**. in CoreNLP

The usual run for command line parameters doesn't give anything

```
java -cp stanford-parser.jar edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser

EMPTY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support this at the moment, unfortunately.

You can just use the `depparse` model in the CoreNLP pipeline, though, and use the CoreNLP `-filelist` option as you mention.